# Cannot import exported SQL data back because of ORA-01830 error on to_timestamp with format even when all NLS settings match

Tags: oracle, import, localization, sqlplus

I did a full export of my database using Oracle SQL Developer 18.2.0.
Then I collected all the NLS settings to be able to apply them back when importing through `sqlplus` tool. I used the following script to collect NLS session values:

```
select 'ALTER SESSION SET ' || parameter || ' = ''' || value || ''';'
from nls_session_parameters where parameter like 'NLS_%'
```

It gave me the following results:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'LATVIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'LATVIA';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = 'Ls';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_ISO_CURRENCY = 'LATVIA';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = 'GREGORIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'RRRR.MM.DD';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'LATVIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = 'LATVIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'RRRR.MM.DD HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'RRRR.MM.DD HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY = 'Ls';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'BINARY';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'BYTE';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP = 'FALSE';
```

So I copied these lines into the very beginning of my exported SQL file.

Then I ran `sqlplus` tool to test if the file can be imported back:

```
sqlplus demo/demo @my_exported_data.sql
```

But still I got the following error:

```
Insert into DEMO.ACCOUNT (ID,LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID,LAST_MODIFIED) values ('1','1',
to_timestamp('2018.10.24 16:39:39,000000000','RRRR.MM.DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'))
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

The session parameters were applied because I saw 17 `Session altered.` messages before the error.

I copied the same SQL query line back into Oracle SQL Developer worksheet and executed it - it ran without errors.

It seems, I'm missing some session setting which is working for SQL Developer and is not working for `sqlplus`.

What is wrong here? How do I find the missing setting and apply it to `sqlplus` session to be able to import the data back?

Edited with more information from comments:

I ran the same NLS value gathering script inside sqlplus, paying special attention to decimal separator - it gave the same values.

But I also ran the following:

```
select systimestamp from dual;
```

and got a difference!

Oracle SQL Developer outputs:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP                        
------------------------------------
2018.10.24 18:30:08,837000000 +03:00
```

but sqlplus outputs:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018.10.24 18:30:45,342000 +03:00
```

So, as one commentator suggested, it might have something to do with timestamp precision. For some reason, SQL Developer exports and imports back with greater precision than sqlplus accepts. Now I have to find the setting that controls timestamp precision for current session.

*There have been many similar questions but in those cases the issue was some forgotten NLS setting or ignored time format. In my case, it seems I have done everything possible to duplicate the session NLS settings from Oracle SQL Developer to `sqlplus` tool, but still it doesn't work.*

Comment: But then why SQL Developer can import it just fine but sqlplus cannot? I'm using the same DB server to import back, so it should work the same, no matter if SQL Developer or sqlplus. Unless SQL Developer is doing some "black magic".

Comment: The error implies that the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting isn't sticking. Possibly either something is resetting it (but you'd have noticed...), or possibly your script re-connects as the `demo` user... which seems unlikely. Can you repeat the query that shows you the current settings inside your script, right before the insert? At least for that specific setting.

Comment: Good idea! I just tried it - the result was exactly the same, I even run a diff tool but both outputs from SQL Developer and inside sqlplus gave the same values for NLS parameters. So, there might be some other unknown session value affecting to_timestamp.

Comment: No, I don't think so; the only setting you're relying on there is for the X (radix character), which is being set to a comma from `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`. You could change the format mask to use an explicit comma instead of the X, but that's just avoidng the issue, not explaining it... Interesting.

Comment: I edited the question because just found a difference of timestamp precision output. That might be the cause there, but not sure how to fix it. I don't want to manually replace all the values in the exported file. There must be some setting which controls this precision.

Comment: Try `FF9` instead of `FF` for the fractional second part of your timestamp format. If you don't specify precision, the default is 6, which can't be changed.

Comment: I don't think that should affect how `to_timestamp()` works, or give the error you're seeing. You can force it to error by using FF6, but left as plain FF it shouldn't error. I think. The evidence suggests I'm wrong, of course... but I can't reproduce what you're seeing (but I do get the same precision you do for systimestamp in SQL Developer and SQL\*Plus). So, does it still error with X changed to a comma in the `to_timestamp` mask? And I'd assumed you were doing both inserts against the same DB, is that true?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it on the same DB (11gR2 Express Edition), on Windows 10.  But now, after I rebooted my PC and ran the same script again, it suddenly imported the data and I cannot reproduce the problem anymore... Not sure, what's going on there, I didn't change a line.